# Fixed Div Position on iPhone

Tags: jquery, html, iphone, css, mobile

I have a div which has rotating images as a background. There is content on top of that which should scroll freely. This all works fine on desktop, but on iPhone, the background div scrolls along with the content. I've tried looking for jQuery solutions to keep the div fixed, but to no avail so far.

The site in question is http://electrickiwi.co.uk/test/barluath/about.html

I want the background div to stay static while the user is scrolling and to remove the space at the bottom caused by the status bar on iPhone. What is the best solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried overflow-y:scroll on the wrapper?

Comment: @reekogi Yes, but the background div still scrolls.

Comment: I think this might help -> http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/2011/fixed-elements-and-scrolling-divs-in-ios-5/ Particularly the viewport tag and 'Fixing the Scrolling Element'

Comment: It looks like it is working fine now. http://cl.austin.pe/image/161C0d3L0G2k
edit: nevermind.